# Why doesn't this JS & PHP code work? (I am trying to send a value from JS to PHP)

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, post

I have a file named **`sample.php`** and it has this code in it, whose task is to just POST a variable value from JS to PHP through AJAX. Here's the code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var ThunkableWebviewerExtension = {
        receiveMessage: function(fxn) {
            var callbackFunction = function(event) {
                if (typeof fxn === 'function') {
                    fxn(event.data)
                }
            };
            document.addEventListener('message', callbackFunction, false);
            window.addEventListener('message', callbackFunction, false);
        }
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var value;
  ThunkableWebviewerExtension.receiveMessage(function(message) {
      value = message; //this is the value I want to send to PHP
  });
  
//sending the value with ajax (POST)

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        $.ajax({
          url : "./sample.php", //same file
          method : "POST",
          data: {"data": value},
          
          success : (res) => {
            resolve(res)
          },
          error : (res) => {
            reject(res)
          }
        })
  })
</script>

<?php
echo $_POST['data']; //nothing comes here...
?>

</body>
</html>
```

My only aim is to access the `value` variable's value (which is in JS side) in PHP. I came to know that this could be done with AJAX, so I tried but it didn't work - the PHP code doesn't echo anything... Where's the problem?

Alternative methods (for accessing a JS variable's value in PHP) are more than welcome. :)

Answer (score 1):

First, in order to run the ajax function, you need [jQuery](https://code.jquery.com/). Then you have to remove the `promise` from the ajax call because according to the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) - "The jqXHR objects returned by $.ajax() as of jQuery 1.5 implement the Promise interface, giving them all the properties, methods, and behavior of a Promise"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var ThunkableWebviewerExtension = {
        receiveMessage: function(fxn) {
            var callbackFunction = function(event) {
                if (typeof fxn === 'function') {
                    fxn(event.data)
                }
            };
            document.addEventListener('message', callbackFunction, false);
            window.addEventListener('message', callbackFunction, false);
        }
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var value ;
  ThunkableWebviewerExtension.receiveMessage(function(message) {
      value = message; //this is the value I want to send to PHP
  });
  
//sending the value with ajax (POST)
$.ajax({
          url : "./sample.php", //same file
          method : "POST",
          data: {"data": value},
          
          success : (res) => {
            console.log(res);
          },
          error : (res) => {
            console.log(res);
          }
        })
</script>
<?php
echo $_POST['data']; //nothing comes here...
?>
</body>
</html>
```

If you come up with `Undefined Index: data` error after adding this solution, you can add a sample value to the `value` variable in your JS Code.

Comment: Vote up for your answer, but it's good to be explained why removing the Promise. According to the documentation - "The jqXHR objects returned by $.ajax() as of jQuery 1.5 implement the Promise interface, giving them all the properties, methods, and behavior of a Promise", so yes you're right that the Promise can be removed! - https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/